# How to restart Python Runtime in Microsoft Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

## Overview

I am trying to restart the Python 3.8.6 runtime inside a Linux Azure Function. Is this possible and if so, how can I do it?

## Context

I am experiencing an issue with Linux Python Azure Functions and ObsPy as indicated in: https://github.com/obspy/obspy/issues/2745

I cannot call the `get_stations` Python function from the ObsPy library to run in Linux, but I can on my local Windows machine. From the thread, it seems a probable cause is the plugin system isn't working. So one of the proposed solutions is to 'reload the runtime' so that plugins used for reading files are re-registered.

How can I do this in a Python Azure Functions running on Linux?

I've tried:

- Making another Azure Function in the same Python Azure Function on Linux which executes os.kill. I ran that function manually using the test interface on Azure, then I ran the "main: function running ObsPy. That didn't fix the issue.
- There' no real option to restart the function, on the current portal, but there is a command that can restart the function using the Azure CLI:

`az functionapp restart --name <functionappName> --resource-group <resourceGroup>`

I ran it in verbose mode to confirm it did something and then ran the main function again. I'm still experiencing the error.

## Environment

ObsPy version = 1.2.2, Python version = 3.8.6 and Platform Linux (Azure Function)
Installed ObsPy using Pip, Python using the downloadable installer

Comment: Hmm, if you write to the `wwwroot` directory the function should reload automatically, however i'm not convinced this is the best approach here.

Comment: Do you know how I can do this manually in Python? 

Not sure if related but I've noticed that the Advanced Tools are missing for Python Linux Functions apps even though I can see it under Net Core Windows Function apps.